# Arduino led strip mosfets irfz44n

Tags: arduino, mosfet, led-strip

So i want to make a rgb led strip setup with irfz44n mosfets. The datasheet says that once 4.5v is applied on the gate the mosfet will start to let through about 9 amps. My psu is only 5 amps. Does this mean i can't dim the colors when using the arduino's analog pins?

EDIT:
Sorry for not being clear. I want to power my common anode led strip with a 12v 5a psu. Every color (red, green blue obviously) is connected to his own mosfet's drain, source pin going back to the psu's and arduino's ground. The gate i want to power with an arduinos analog pin. My question now is, will i be able to dim the leds since the gate-to-source picture on the datasheet says at 4.5 volts on the gate the mosfet will start to let 9 amps flowing from drain to source.

Comment: It means you haven't enough power to *light* your LEDs.

Comment: I don't see a link to your LEDs nor a schematic?

Comment: try phrasing as '... the mosfet will start to let through up to 9 amps'.

Comment: voting to close as unclear, since without schematic, it's not clear what OP really tries to do.

Comment: You really don't want to **analog** dim the LEDs. Your MOSFETs will be dropping a lot of power and will get quite hot. You need to use PWM dimming.

Answer (score 2):

IRFZ44N can't be driven from 5V (the datasheet specifies no RdsON for Vgs=5V).

See this answer, which is basically the same problem, and use the same FET.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/322098/13616

Answer (score 0):

Regarding current.

*let through about 9 amps*

9 Amp is the maximum current the MOSFET can handle at that VGS without becoming to hot and break down and fail. If your LED consumes 5 Amp then you are below the maximum limit of 9 Amp = OK!

Comment: So i will be able to dim the leds although the minimum volt stated on the gate in the datasheet is 4.5v?

Comment: I would use a additional transistor to increase the VGS on the MOSFET. https://arduinodiy.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/fet2_thumb.gif?w=535

Comment: Two bullets: 1. IRFZ44N isn't a suitable MOSFET, look for a MOSFET with TTL level. 2. If you have to use IRFZ44N Phillips datasheet shows it can be driven with VGS 6 Volt but poorly.